# Problema com JSF durante validação no formulário

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, jsf-2.2

*Estou com um problema no formulário de cadastro de animais:

Segue a parte do diagrama envolvido no relacionamento referente ao formulário:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
*O problema é que quando estou realizando o cadastro de um animal, eu consigo por o nome, idade, sexo e o tipo de animal (que no caso é de outra tabela). Já no campo Cliente eu consigo preencher com o dado, porém na hora de clicar em salvar, aparece na tela q falta preencher o campo do cliente sendo que o mesmo foi preenchido.*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Segue os códigos do projeto:**

> Classe *Pessoa*:

```
package dominio.modelo;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Pessoa {

    @Id
    @Column(length=14)
    private String cpf;

    @Column(length=25, nullable=false)
    protected String nome;

    @Column(length=25, nullable=false)
    private String sobrenome;

    @Column(length=9, nullable=true)
    private String telefone;

    public Pessoa() {

    }

    public Pessoa(String cpf, String nome, String sobrenome, String telefone) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.sobrenome = sobrenome;
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getSobrenome() {
        return sobrenome;
    }

    public void setSobrenome(String sobrenome) {
        this.sobrenome = sobrenome;
    }

    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((cpf == null) ? 0 : cpf.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Pessoa other = (Pessoa) obj;
        if (cpf == null) {
            if (other.cpf != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!cpf.equals(other.cpf))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

> Classe *Cliente*

```
package dominio.modelo;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Cliente extends Pessoa {

    @Column(length=20, nullable=true)
    private int credito;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="cliente", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Animal> animais;

    public Cliente() {
        super();
    }

    public Cliente(String cpf, String nome, String sobrenome, String telefone) {
        super(cpf, nome, sobrenome, telefone);
    }

    public int getcredito() {
        return credito;
    }

    public void setCredito(int credito) {
        this.credito = credito;
    }

    public List<Animal> getAnimais() {
        return animais;
    }

    public void setAnimais(List<Animal> animais) {
        this.animais = animais;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return nome;
    }

}
```

> Classe *Animal*

```
package dominio.modelo;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;

@Entity
public class Animal {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="ID_ANIMAL")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="ID_ANIMAL", sequenceName="SEQ_ID_ANIMAL", initialValue=1 ,allocationSize=1)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(length=25, nullable=false)
    private String nome;

    private Integer idade;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String sexo;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_cliente")
    private Cliente cliente;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="tipo")
    private Tipo tipo;

    public Animal() {
        super();
    }

    public Animal(Integer id, String nome, Integer idade, String sexo) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.idade = idade;
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getIdStr() {
        if (this.id == null)
            return "";

        return id.toString();
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public String getNomeStr() {
        if (this.nome == null)
            return "";

        return nome.toString();
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Integer getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setIdade(Integer idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }

    public String getSexo() {
        if (this.sexo == null)
            return "";

        return sexo.toString();
    }

    public String getSexoStr() {
        if (this.sexo == null)
            return "";

        return sexo.toString();
    }

    public void setSexo(String sexo) {
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }

    public Cliente getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

    public Tipo getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(Tipo tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

}
```

> Classe *Tipo*

```
package dominio.modelo;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;

@Entity
public class Tipo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="ID_TIPO")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="ID_TIPO", sequenceName="SEQ_ID_TIPO", initialValue=1 ,allocationSize=1)
    private Integer codigo;

    @Column(unique=true)
    private String nome;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="tipo")
    private List<Animal> animais;

    public Tipo() {
        super();
    }

    public Tipo(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }


    public Integer getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public List<Animal> getAnimais() {
        return animais;
    }

    public void setAnimais(List<Animal> animais) {
        this.animais = animais;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return nome;
    }

}
```

> Página *editarAnimal.xhtml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<ui:composition template="modelo.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="">Edição de Animal</ui:define>

    <ui:define name="conteudo">
        <p:panelGrid columns="2">

            <ui:remove>
                <p:outputLabel for="id" value="ID:" />
                <p:inputText id="id" value="#{animalMB.animal.id}" required="true" />
            </ui:remove>

            <p:outputLabel for="nome" value="Nome:" />
            <p:inputText id="nome" value="#{animalMB.animal.nome}" required="true" />

            <p:outputLabel for="idade" value="Idade:" />
            <p:inputText id="idade" value="#{animalMB.animal.idade}" required="true" />

            <p:outputLabel for="sexo" value="Sexo:" />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="sexo" value="#{animalMB.animal.sexo}" required="true">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Selecione" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="M" itemLabel="Macho" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="F" itemLabel="Fêmea" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>

            <p:outputLabel for="cliente" value="Cliente:" />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="cliente" value="#{animalMB.animal.cliente}" converter="cliente-converter" required="true">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Selecione" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{animalMB.clientes}" var="cli" itemLabel="#{cli.nome}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>

            <p:outputLabel for="tipo" value="Tipo:" />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="tipo" value="#{animalMB.animal.tipo}" converter="tipo-converter" required="true">
                <f:selectItems value="#{animalMB.tipos}" var="tipo" itemLabel="#{tipo.nome}"></f:selectItems>
            </p:selectOneMenu>

            <h:outputLabel value="" />

            <h:panelGroup>
                <p:commandLink ajax="false" value="Salvar" action="#{animalMB.acaoSalvar}" />
            -
            <p:commandLink ajax="false" immediate="true" value="Cancelar" action="#{animalMB.acaoListar}" />

            </h:panelGroup>

        </p:panelGrid>

    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
</html>
```

Comment: Falta a propriedade `itemValue` no seu p:selectItems de cliente e tipo.

Comment: pera, faltou onde?

no **<f:selectItems>** ou no **<p:selectOneMenu>** ??

Comment: No `f:selectItems`.

Comment: Então tenho que fazer a alteração de:  
<f:selectItems `value=`"#{animalMB.clientes}" var="cli" itemLabel="#{cli.nome}" />  

para  

<f:selectItems `itemValue`="#{animalMB.clientes}" var="cli" itemLabel="#{cli.nome}" />  

?

Comment: coloca ocódigo do seu converter de cliente

Comment: @HenriqueSantiago segue o ClienteConverter https://ghostbin.com/paste/craw2

Comment: @RenanNarciso cara, não está carregando.

Comment: @HenriqueSantiago o que não está carregando?

Answer (score 0):

Falta a propriedade `itemValue` no seu `f:selectItems`, ela serve para setar o cliente no objeto animal do seu *managed bean* animalMB. Como você declarou um converter e ele constrói o objeto cliente a partir de um `cpf` então passe a propriedade `cpf` no `itemValue` do `f:selectItems`.

```
<p:outputLabel for="cliente" value="Cliente:" />
<p:selectOneMenu id="cliente" value="#{animalMB.animal.cliente}" converter="cliente-converter" required="true">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Selecione" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{animalMB.clientes}" var="cli" itemValue="#{cli.cpf}" itemLabel="#{cli.nome}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Fiz o que foi pedido e a falha ainda persiste.

Comment: Aparece algum erro além do erro da interface? Você pode postar o código do AnimalMB e do cliente-converter?

Comment: coloquei um try/catch no método salvar pra ver o **e.printstacktrace** e me mostrar algum erro no log, porém n apareceu...


AnimalMB - https://ghostbin.com/paste/gbfhz  
ClienteConverter - https://ghostbin.com/paste/craw2

Comment: @RenanNarciso, eu alterei na minha resposta. Além do `itemValue` que estava faltando eu não me atentei que você estava utilizando um converter para cliente, esse converter espera um `cpf` para montar o objeto cliente então modifiquei minha resposta.

Comment: Cara, fiz o que foi pedido. Coloquei a propriedade `itemValue="#{cli.cpf}"` e o erro persiste, nada de salvar... Fica dando erro de validação: **Cliente: Erro de validação: o valor é necessário.**